# Detox does not complete test which runs a network request

Tags: detox

I have a button where it calls an API, even though the API is completed the test button click does not complete.

> [APP_STATUS] The app is busy with the following tasks: • The event
> "Network Request" is taking place with object: "URL:
> “https://clientstream.launchdarkly.com/meval/eyJjdXN0b20iOnsiaW5zdGFsbGF0aW9uSWQiOiIxMTlhYmY2NC03ZTU3LTQ3MmMtYjRmYS04Nzk5N2QzOWVhNWMiLCJhZ2VudElkIjoiNzZlYjhmMTgtNWVmNi00MzI5LTk3YmUtNzg4YWM0ODUzYjgxIiwiZGV2aWNlIjoiaVBob25lMTIsMSIsIm9zIjoiMTUuMCJ9LCJhbm9ueW1vdXMiOmZhbHNlLCJrZXkiOiIxMTlhYmY2NC03ZTU3LTQ3MmMtYjRmYS04Nzk5N2QzOWVhNWMifQ==”".
> • Run loop "Main Run Loop" is awake. • The event "Network Request" is
> taking place with object: "URL:
> “https://companionmobilebackenddev.azurewebsites.net/api/v2/custommedia”".
> • There are 1 work items pending on the dispatch queue: "Main Queue
> (<OS_dispatch_queue_main: com.apple.main-thread>)". • 1 enqueued
> JavaScript timers:
>
> - Timer #1:
>
>   - JS timer ID: 775.
>   - Duration: 0.001.
>   - Is recurring: NO.

[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same issue.